# Problem in using j2me polish with netbeans

Tags: java, java-me

I have downloaded and installed the j2me polish successfully and i have tried to create the project but there is a reference problem showing that the specified folder does not contain the java platform but it is successfully working with normal project

instead of polish which LWUIT to use?

Answer (score 0):

For an alternative to use instead of Polish, try J4ME:

[J4ME Google Project Page](http://code.google.com/p/j4me/)

It's open source and a strong competitor for Polish. I've used it successfully for several Java ME projects. Setup is easy because you simply need the library in your classpath.